# Plot percentile lines of y-axis data R

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'd like to draw a vertical line on the chart to show where the first standard deviation of data ends from the orderSize data plotted along the x-axis. And for example it looks like the majority of the orderSizes are just under 50.

[image]

```
ggplot(oilData, aes(orderSize,oilPrice)) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_smooth()+
geom_bar() + 
ggtitle("CL 11-17") + 
xlab("OrderSize") + 
ylab("Price") + 
theme(
plot.title = element_text(color="Black", size=14, face="bold"),
axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=11, face="plain"),
axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=11, face="plain")
)
```

Comment: `+ geom_vline(xintercept = sd(oilData$OrderSize, na.rm=T)`

Comment: What does "the first standard deviation of data" mean?